# Unable to set custom ringtone on Moto G 2 after upgrading to Lollipop

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, motorola-moto-g, ringtone

I'm unable to customize the ringtone on my second generation Moto G after upgrading to Lollipop. I tried doing it normally from the Android settings, but just got a default "beep" sound instead. Only the built-in ringtone works properly.

Comment: Well, that's weird ! Haven't heard anything like this from the members over here even I am also having the same Moto G2 and things are working just fine with me ! Means you are the only one having this problem may be you should backup your data and try performing a complete factory reset !

Comment: You may want to look at the answers here, if you have not already: [Custom ringtone not working on Nexus 5 since OTA Lollipop](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/88345/custom-ringtone-not-working-on-nexus-5-since-ota-lollipop)

Comment: I am facing the same problem in MOTO G Gen2. After upgrading to Lollipop, custom ringtone stopped working (If you assign tone to particualr contact, its working, but phone ringtone is not working...) everything else is fine. Please guide me if there is any solution for this.

Comment: Work around for this is here: Convert ur mp3 files to .ogg files and set as ringtone. http://audio.online-convert.com/convert-to-ogg

Comment: Make sure your ring tone file is in internal storage.

Comment: @Santhosh did you find a solution? I have the same problem with same phone!

Comment: I can do it in my Rocket Music player while playing a song there is an option "Ringtone" in the options menu. Whenever a song is playing the song or tone is set as ringtone.

Comment: @AkiRoss, .ogg file works as ringtone. Convert your mp3 to .ogg and set as ringtone. If you don't want to convert to .ogg, try to set a ringtone from file explorer. i.e Install and open ES File Explorer - sdcard - <whatever folder> - open your mp3 file in ES media player - set as ringtone using player options.

Answer (score 2):

Someone put this as an edit instead of an answer:

> Instead of setting ringtone under setting --> Sounds and
>   notifications, try to set your ringtone from your player [Ex: ES File
>   Explorer --> sdcard --> download --> your song. Play this in ES media
>   player --> set ringtone ].

and someone else tried to edit this in:

> 1- change ur choice music into .ogg format (try fx file explorer it may able to rename any format u want)
>   2- put that music file on the ringtone folder on phone
>   where hangout ringtones are present  3-now power off ur phone and
>   start it
>   4-go to phones and notification folder u got ur choice music
>   as a ringtone

Comment: I just tried by moving my required song to device storage, then saved that song in ringtone folder present in sd card folder and set the song as ringtone via file explorer and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Please Try this way, Simply Place the Your Ringtone in FileExplorer-->sdcard-->Ringtones-->yourRingTone file.Its working.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem here's how I solve the problem.

Copy the song you want to set as ringtone to your internal memory / ringtones folder and set it as your ringtone. Note setting ringtone from sd card won't work.