# LG G3 (d855) Lollipop: cannot set custom ringtone

Tags: ringtone, mp3, lg-g3

I'm having a weird situation: I cannot add a custom ringtone to my LG G3.

I made an MP3 file with Audacity, I uploaded it using AirDroid and set it as default ringtone (like I used to do on my GT-I9300 with CyanogenMod) but it won't take it, when I receive a phone call the default LG ringt one is used.
But apparently everything is set up correctly, after setting the ringtone with AirDroid if I go on the phone settings I see the correct file seleced, not LG's one.
I tried playing the audio from there and it works.

To make sure it wasn't a problem with the mp3 file itself I tried:

1. cutting down the size of the file: from a *full song* (3M) I tried stripping it to something like 30s (1M)
2. changing format: the short file, saved as OGG instead of mp3
3. manually uploading in a different directory (instead of using AirDroid)

All tests have the same result: LG's ringtone!

What **works** is using one of the other default ringtones provided by vendor. If I choose one of the existing tones the setting is correctly honored.

I'm getting mad, I don't understand what I am doing wrong.
I'm now running the latest version available for my phone (V20h-EUR-XX). I had Android 4.4 for a week or two, and as far as I can remember (it wasn't my priority) this wasn't working with that version either.

I found a [popular AE question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/88345/custom-ringtone-not-working-on-nexus-5-since-ota-lollipop) about ringtones and Lollipop, but sadly I cannot find the *Clear cached data* option on my LG.

Comment: Did you place the ringtone inside the ringtones directory in the /sdcard folder?

Comment: No, it's in the `/Ringtones` but on the main memory (full path `/storage/emulated/0/Ringtones`). Since Lollipop only system app can write to sdcard, and I haven't rooted the device. Along with my ringtone there are also hangouts_*.ogg files

Comment: have you tried another phone app? Also, /sdcard is symlink to /storage/emulated/[userid]/

Comment: what do you mean with *another phone app*? tried what?

Comment: another dialer. Just search gplay for dialer. Could possibly be bug with stock dialer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the useful suggestion of a [forum post](http://www.androidworld.it/forum/lg-g3-754/suoneria-personalizzata-155913/#post1527741) I managed to fix by

1. copy the ringtone in the `/Music~ folder (instead of`/Ringtones`)
2. start the bundled music player, play the song I want for ringtone, then in the menu select *Use as ringtone*

This way I could finally change the ringtone with a custom one!

Answer (score -1):

U delete the internal memory Ringtones folder then create the small letter use ringtones folder copy the ur song paste the ringtones folder then select the song 
Its work for moto g2

Comment: welcome to android enthusiasts this is very hard to read if you dont use real words like you and your you also have zero punctuation which makes it even harder to read you dont know when one sentence starts and then ends